# Count of Custom Attribute Options

Tags: php, woocommerce

I would like to put a a message to say "available in other colors" on the category page if there is more than one color you can select on the product. Right now I have some code in content.product.php that detects if it's a variable product, but not if there are more than one option for an attribute. Color is a custom attribute.

Right now I have:

```
<?php if($product->product_type == "variable") {  ?>
<h4>Available in other colors.</h4>
<?php } else {  ?>

<?php } ?>
```

It's showing all variable product type with this message. I want to show it only if there are 2 or more colors attached to the product. The products has two attributes on it - size and color. Size always has three or four wheras color sometimes only has one

Comment: Does this work? What is wrong with it? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like this?

```
<?php

if ($product->product_type == "variable") {
    print '<h4>Variable products message.</h4>';
}
else if (count($product->color) > 2) {
    print '<h4>This product is avilable in other colors!</h4>';
}
else {
    #Optional print here..
}

?>
```

I might be wrong all you need to do is test by writing

```
<?php print_r($product); exit;?>
```

see where the colors are beign stored and just replace the `->color` with the proper name. Good luck!

Comment: That wasn't working for me for some reason. When I did the print I never saw anything related to the color. The slug for color is color-swatch.

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working

```
    <?php
$fabric_values = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_color-swatch');


if (count($fabric_values) >= 2) {
    print '<h4>Available in other fabrics.</h4>';
}
else {
    #Optional print here..
}
```

?>